# Why doesn't rust allow float/int division by default?

Tags: rust

The following snippet:

```
let a: f32 = 2.0;
let b: i32 = 12;
println!("{}",a/b);
```

fails to compile, with the error message indicating that there is "no implementation for 'f32 / i32'. Now, I understand what this error means, and that I could easily fix it by casting b before dividing. More to the point, the compiler also tells me that I could fix this without modifying the snippet above by implementing the trait Div<i32> for f32.

I don't actually need to divide ints by floats in this manner, but the compiler's message I got made me curious enough to ask the following question: **why isn't Div<i32> already implemented for f32?**

Of course it would be pretty easy for anyone to implement this by themselves, but I assume it must mean something that it's not a default feature. Is there some complication with the implementation I'm not thinking of? Or is it that the possibility of f32/i32 division somehow lead to "language gotcha's"? Or maybe it's just that rust is more "barebones" in this regard than I assumed?

Comment: Short form: Yes, there are gotchas here. Look at how many people have been confused by Python's division, expecting it to either return a float when it actually returns an int or the inverse. Making people be explicit about their intent is good practice.

Comment: "Of course it would be pretty easy for anyone to implement this by themselves" actually that impossible

Comment: There also the question of even choosing a default. Should the language always cast the integer to floating-point beforehand and return a floating point, or should it cast the float to an integer beforehand and return an integer? It's a similar idea to why Rust prevents auto-casting between signed and unsigned integer types. There's no obvious and safe default, so make the programmer decide exactly what they want.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple reasons. For one, it's not clear what the return values should be. Should `12 / 2.0` return a float or an integer? What about `12.0 / 2`? Many languages opt to just return floats, but this results in hidden conversion costs. Rust as a language tries to be very explicit, especially in case of non-zero cost abstractions.

There is also type safety to consider. Sometimes doing arithmetic between ints and floats indicates a logic error.